# Differences in pgsql and psql

Tags: postgresql

I am a newbie of Postgresql. I found that we can't switch database in PgAmin Query Tools, but we can switch by using `(\connect or \c)` in PSQl. What is the reason behind?

Comment: `\c` is not a `SQL` command - all starting with \`\ are `psql` specific commands. PgAdmin is designed to run sql scripts, not `psql` ones

Answer (score 1):

PgAmin allows you to connect to the database. just click on it and it tries to.
`psql` does the same. but instead of clicking yoiu have to type `\c DBNAME`

you probably meant "why I can't script connecting to db in pgadmin as I can in psql"?.. then the answer: "because `psql` is a CLI, so you can script even launching itself from the `shell`. Meanwhile PgAdmin is a GUI and is not meant to be scripted"

Comment: If so, how would I switch database in PgAdmin Query Tools? Because I want to create a  new database and create tables in it. example as below: **create database aa; \connect aa; create table tbl1....**

Comment: 1. connect to any db, 2. type " create database aa;" in Query tool, 3. press F5 to run the `SQL` statement, 4. click on the newly appeared aa database 5. swith in Query tool to a new database or just open a new Query tool, 6 type "create table tbl1..." or just use `psql` if you want to script it all